# How to print the properties of all the files with last 2 versions of SVN repository?

Tags: svn, command-line

I am able to print the properties of all the SVN files under a directory which are having only one version. But there are some files with two versions and am unable to print those files properties.

```
> svn log -l2 -v 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
r2 | author | 2016-11-22 01:43:37 +0530 (Tue, 22 Nov 2016) | 1 line Changed paths: /trunk/sample/filename.zip 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
r1 | author | 2016-11-21 01:43:37 +0530 (Mon, 21 Nov 2016) | 1 line Changed paths: /trunk/sample/filename.zip
```

This command is retrieving only one file.But there are more than 1000 files with 2 versions.

Can someone please help on this.Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of the command please?

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | author | 2016-11-22 01:43:37 +0530 (Tue, 22 Nov 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   /trunk/sample/filename.zip
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1| author | 2016-11-21 01:43:37 +0530 (Mon, 21 Nov 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
    /trunk/sample/filename.zip

Comment: Btw, is it for your reference or any help on this?

Comment: In which directory are you executing the command? What do you mean by "for your reference"?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this information will help. 
The revision in the SVN Repository are repository wide and command `svn log` operates on path. Whatever path you are inside the repository it will operate on that path. 
Like in your case it is only working on path `/trunk/sample/`. Probably you have files that are outside this folder `sample` and in the main folder of `trunk`.

Have a look at my example and observe that how i get two different outputs by running the same `svn log` command but from different paths.

Example 1 path `trunk/package`

```
e:\PersonalProjects\Python\GenericEngineSF\trunk\package>svn log -l2 -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r38 | pnaishan | 2018-06-25 10:05:44 +0530 (Mon, 25 Jun 2018) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/package/mainApp.py

-clear previous exceptions
-clear dictionary to update list of tests
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r37 | pnaishan | 2018-06-25 09:42:37 +0530 (Mon, 25 Jun 2018) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/main.py
   M /trunk/package/logApp.py
   M /trunk/package/mainApp.py

-Changes to work with standalone exe
-print error for user

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example 2 path /trunk/

```
e:\PersonalProjects\Python\GenericEngineSF\trunk>svn log -l2 -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r40 | k10blogger | 2018-06-25 17:22:23 +0530 (Mon, 25 Jun 2018) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/build

Remove Build.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r39 | k10blogger | 2018-06-25 17:21:28 +0530 (Mon, 25 Jun 2018) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/build

Temporary commit will be reverted back.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So you see for `svn log` path do matter and as we change the path the output also changes.

Also the flag you are using `-l` is to limit the log viewing to only last two entires. If you want to see properties of all the files than you need to iteratively call `svn log` and pass the filenames or directory names like as follows:

```
e:\PersonalProjects\Python\GenericEngineSF\trunk>svn log pyscripts -l2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r23 | k10blogger | 2018-06-13 20:29:23 +0530 (Wed, 13 Jun 2018) | 1 line

Renamed and Created the Template_Script_1.py and Template_Script_2.py.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | k10blogger | 2018-06-11 11:10:42 +0530 (Mon, 11 Jun 2018) | 1 line

Commited Changes for Utilities and mainApp
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This shows the last 2 changes for the directory `pyscripts` similary you can get the same for other files and directories.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not working properly or am not executing it correctly. I went to the last subfolder and executed this command where there are no files with 2 versions. But it retrieved all the files under the parent folder which are having single version. Please let me know how do i resolve this.

Comment: so just for my clarification. You have a subfolder say _s1_ where you have files _xfile_ and _yfile_. At revision say _r20_ you created _xfile_ and at revision _r28_ you created _yfile_. Assume _s1_ is at location `trunk/s1`. So at path `trunk/s1` you executed this `svn log -l2 -v` and you didnt see the revision r20 and r28 on the screen instead you saw some other revisions? Is there a way you can share a snapshot?

Comment: Okay, let me put it in this way. This is the folder structure "/trunk/test/abc/xyz" where 'xyz' is the subfolder which is having files with only one version (say r15). Now, when I executed the command 'svn log -l2 -v' under this path "/trunk/test/abc/xyz", it is retrieving me the files from 'test' folder.And , those files also have single version. My goal is to retrieve all the files having two versions at any given path. Dont want single version and three version files. As per your answer above, the path do matters. But it's not working for me as I explained. Please help on this.

Comment: Hope it gave you some clarity. Else, pls let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Okay so you want to display logs of all files at a given path that have been modified exactly twice. Is this a correct inference?

Comment: Yes, the only files having two versions.It would be great if we can retrieve by executing the command at the parent folder itself (i.e, traversing through all the subfolders and display if at all those folders have 2 version files).

Comment: Okay so there is no native command from svn to perform this task. This is because subversion revision number applies to the entire repository tree and not to the individual files. Each revision represents a state of the tree at that revision. What can be done is that we need to write a loop to extract svn log information from all the files in your repository tree if for a file the length of log is exactly 2 then that is the file that you need. This can probably be written in a bash or a python script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180060/discussion-between-siddharth-kaul-and-rahul).

Comment: Thanks alot mate. Pls check the chat box.